# Java spring parametric .xml config file

Tags: java, xml, spring, jar

I have a Spring Java 1.8 project exported in a .jar. When I want to run this Java .jar application, I'd like to give a file into the argument which .xml config file should the program use in the relative folder. I tried so many ways, but none of them works.

For example:

> sampleJavaPorgram.jar config1.xml

(config1.xml and sampleJavaProgram.jar is in the same directory)

shoud load config1.xml like that:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config1.xml");
```

Comment: *"tried so many ways, but none of them works"* is not a useful way to describe what you've already tried and how it failed.

Comment: I tried that I using command-line arguement in Main, like that:

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("args[0]l");

But didn't work.

Comment: `"args[0]l"` is just a String literal. Your application must've exploded, not just *"didn't work"*. It's easy to find the correct way of doing this if you try to search.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. Obviously I meant to be write:

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(args[0]);

Comment: UP_this_thread. I have same issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use [Command-Line Argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html), to get name of this XML file and then pass it to AppContext.

Or you might use [System properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)